# High resolution Output for Blender 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I need some advice for the output settings in Blender 2.8...

When I render an image with 2000px x 2000px the output has the resolution of 72x72.

[image]

Now when I render the same image with 3000px x 3000px the output resolution is... still 72x72. When zoomed in the image shows ugly pixels...

[image]

So: Is there a chance / way to have the resolution output at 300x300 (ppcm)? The only solution I came up with is to increase the image size massively... and therefore the rendertimes insanely.

Let's see if you guys can come up with an answer. Thnx

Comment: What image format are you using.

Comment: I have no idea what you 72*72 resolution means but when it comes to digital images only pixel resolution matters. If you have a 2k by 2k image it's already a pretty high resolution image. The aliasing your see on image 2 is most likely do to seeing a re-scaled image displayed into a viewer (i.e pixels aren't lining with your screen, therefore you encounter aliasing).

Comment: It's dots per inch (DPI). @ArthurBlaquart is absolutely right here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean dpi – dots per inch – markets default high resolution print setting.

If you're not printing, only pixel resolution matters, and it's basically the same scenario with a different resolution:

- a 3000x3000px image at 72 dpi is 105x105cm.
- a 3000x3000px image at 300 dpi is 25x25cm.

A high dpi image not necessarily will be crystal clear when you zoom in. Only the size in pixels count when you're looking at the screen.